# How could we deal with user's input in case no internet connection

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I think that we all deal comfortably with programming in case there is an Internet connection, especially if we are dealing with a server , But gentlemen, there are terrifying and disturbing results in the event that the user does not have an Internet connection , Imagine that there is a server connected to the Internet that interacts with the user's input , I often wonder what is the global applications use in such a case

**I'm going to make it simple what is the problem I'm facing**

i am building flutter app using dart and Firebase ..
well lets say  user sent data to `firestore` Let's say it's a message for example

```
int count ; 
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(widget.documentUid).doc(currentUser.uid).set({ 
     "timestamp": DateTime.now(),
     "name": currentUser.name,
     "receiverUid": widget.documentUid,
     "countM" : count++ 
     });
```

well everything going to be perfect here If the user has an internet connection .

What I noticed is that the same process in the event that there is no internet connection is that the data sent will not wait for the connection again and therefore the process will be canceled .. This is a shame :( .. user will never accept like this app .. and it is only a example from many like count messages and delete messages and read messages which i developed them to be Responsive with the server how could i deal with this problem ..

and please no one tell me to chick internet state before , because this process it self will never make data to wait ,

**Is there a data caching control?**

**Is there a library that handles this?**

**Is there a way to control the user's input in in case no Internet connection and make it wait until the connection again and execute without losing anything**?

**Is there anything important that I missed?**

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This process is not automated. You will have to handle offline/online cases yourself.

This package allows you to stream the connectivity status:
https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus

You can use this with provider to rebuild UI whenever the stream changes.

Also, firebase itself has some level of caching, but I would recommend using an offline database like hive to sync with your online data incase internet connection is lost. You can also store the state of your navigator in the database when connection is lost and switch to the offline database. When connection is back, reload the state and continue. If only online data is to be shown, make a page which shows internet connectivity lost and switch the UI using the connectivity stream.

As for messages, don't use async on your firestore writes and it will automatically write to the database when internet connection is back on. But again, if the app was closed when internet was lost, this won't happen. To enable this, when internet goes offline, store the messages in the hive db and then when its back online or the user starts the app with internet, it will push the messages with the relevant timestamps.

Comment: thanks a lot RealRK , This is what I am looking for .. Can you provide me with the names of servers that are not connected to the Internet .. How can I search for these things .. Is this possible with Firbase? i mean does Firbase has like this server .. offline ?

Comment: I don't understand, you can't get 'servers' without internet. Hive db is a local on device database and not on the cloud. You can set it up to sync certain data from firestore. Firebase servers cannot be accessed when offline.

Comment: you said "but I would recommend using an offline database" i only ask if Firebase provide this service

Comment: Firebase does have some level of provisions here. Check this out: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Comment: Although, I would recommend using your own database which stores your custom data models since that is more reliable overall.